# SQL Server Inner Join on Same Table

Tags: sql-server

I have a query to fetch records for a given `DEVICEID` using inner join on the same table. Please guide me how fetch the records for the Set of Device ID's rather than one.

This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    X.DeviceId, Y.RecordedTime, X.RecordedTime,
    (DATEDIFF(SECOND, Y.RecordedTime, X.RecordedTime)) SECONDS
FROM 
    (SELECT  
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER RecordedTime DESC) SNO,
         [GCId],
         [DeviceId], [IgnitionStatus], [TruckNo],
         [TripId], [RecordedTime], [UploadTime], [SyncTime], EventCode
     FROM 
         [KYTE].[dbo].[KT_savetest1] 
     WHERE 
         DeviceId = '861693034654582' 
         AND (RecordedTime > '2018-01-22 00:00:05' AND
              RecordedTime < '2018-01-22 00:23:55')
         AND EventCode IN (1, 101)) X
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RecordedTime DESC) SNO,
         [GCId], [DeviceId], [IgnitionStatus], [TruckNo],
         [TripId], [RecordedTime], [UploadTime], [SyncTime], EventCode 
     FROM 
         [KYTE].[dbo].[KT_savetest1] 
     WHERE
         DeviceId = '861693034654582' 
         AND (RecordedTime > '2018-01-22 00:00:05' AND
              RecordedTime < '2018-01-22 00:23:59') 
         AND EventCode IN (1, 101)) Y ON X.SNO = Y.SNO - 1 
WHERE
    (DATEDIFF(SECOND, Y.RecordedTime, X.RecordedTime)) > 60
```

Result

```
86169303883567  2018-01-21 23:40:52   2018-01-21 23:41:53   61  1
86169303883567  2018-01-21 23:27:55   2018-01-21 23:28:56   61  1
86169303883567  2018-01-21 23:02:01   2018-01-21 23:03:02   61  1
86169303883567  2018-01-21 22:49:04   2018-01-21 22:50:05   61  1
```

Comment: mysql or sqlserver? can you remove incorrect tag please.And add data as text from which your expected result is derived.

Comment: yes Sir, SQL Server

Comment: The first ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER RecordedTime DESC)  is missing a by.

Comment: If you are on sqlserver 2012 or above LAG may be a better option if not have you tried partition by in the row_number statement?